# Order results from two queries based on time in second query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to get the result order by time but because im using a sql query  into a while of an other sql query i get the result ordered by `$arrID`

```
$req1==mysql_query("SELECT friendId FROM friends ");
while($res1=mysql_fetch_row($req1)) {
    $arrID = $res['friendId'];

    $req = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE postby=$arrID  ORDER BY posttime DESC ");
    while ($res = mysql_fetch_row($req)) {
        echo $res['bostby'];
        echo $res['postcontent'];
    }
}
```

the result is :

```
post 1 by 2 content aaaaaaaa  time: 11:60
post 2 by 2 content bbbbbbbb   time 11:59
post 3 by 2 content aaaaaaaa  time: 11:58
post 4 by 2 content bbbbbbbb   time 11:56
post 5 by 3 content aaaaaaaa  time: 11:61
post 6 by 3 content bbbbbbbb   time 11:60
post 7 by 3 content aaaaaaaa  time: 11:59
post 8 by 5 content bbbbbbbb   time 12:20
post 8 by 5 content bbbbbbbb   time 12:19
```

and i need the resut to be order by time not by id

```
post 8 by 5 content bbbbbbbb   time 12:20
post 8 by 5 content bbbbbbbb   time 12:19
post 1 by 2 content aaaaaaaa  time: 11:60
post 6 by 3 content bbbbbbbb   time 11:60
post 2 by 2 content bbbbbbbb   time 11:59
post 7 by 3 content aaaaaaaa  time: 11:59
```

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: _**thanks** for the advice but can you solve this plz??_

Comment: And don't use a query in a while of another query. See JOINs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a single query that joins the two tables, instead of doing nested loops.

```
SELECT p.* FROM posts AS p
JOIN friends AS f ON p.postby = f.friendId
ORDER BY p.posttime DESC
```

From your comment, it appears your first query isn't so simple. But you can join with a subquery.

```
SELECT p.* FROM posts AS p
JOIN (
    SELECT user_from AS friendId
    FROM friend_requests 
    WHERE user_to = $SessionID AND accepted = '1'
    UNION
    SELECT user_to AS friendId
    FROM friend_requests
    WHERE user_from = $SessionID AND accepted = '1'
) AS f ON p.postby = f.friendId
ORDER BY p.posttime DESC
```

Comment: _**it's a little bit complicated ,actually i've use this reqq** _                                                 
                                                                                                                 
         `$reqz="SELECT  user_from FROM friend_requests WHERE ( user_to=".$SessionID." AND accepted='1' )UNION 
     SELECT user_to FROM friend_requests WHERE  (user_from=".$SessionID." AND accepted='1')";
    $resz=mysql_query($reqz);
    while($rowz=mysql_fetch_row($resz)) {

        $arrID = $rowz[0];`

Comment: Replace `JOIN friends` with `JOIN (SELECT ... UNION SELECT ...)`

Comment: **_Can u plz fix the hole code for me !? :D_ **

Comment: Refresh and you'll see it.

Comment: **OMG :o **    `C:\wamp64\www\MY PROJECT\Hometest.php:18:boolean false`

Comment: I had the wrong capitalization of `$SessionID`. Try it now.

Comment: thank you much master :D its work very well :D :D

Comment: When you're debugging, make sure you have `error_reporting(E_ALL);` enabled. Then you would have seen the warning about the typo in the variable name.

Comment: **i really need great people like u around me ; im working at my final study project and i got many issues**

Comment: What are you studying? Not MySQL evidently!

Comment: sure im studying java / php / sql /  ... generally web devoleppment :D but im not proffesionell